# Kotlin Jetpack, How to load drawables using string array

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable

I am loading images from `drawables` folder to the `buttons` with following code.

```
Icon(
    painter=painterResource(R.drawable.imageName),
    modifier=Modifier.size(30.dp),
    contentDescription="drawable icons",
    tint=Color.Unspecified
)
```

But I want to use that code in a loop with a `string array` such as

```
val imageNames = arrayOf("image1", "image2")

for (k in imageNames.indices) {
      Icon(
          painter=painterResource(R.drawable.imageNames[k]),
          modifier=Modifier.size(30.dp),
          contentDescription="drawable icons",
          tint=Color.Unspecified
       )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawables should be drawable value resources not `String` in your case

```
val imageNames = arrayOf("image1", "image2")
```

Should be

```
val imageRes = arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_1, R.drawable.ic_2)

imageRes.forEach { res ->
     Icon(
         painter=painterResource(res),
         modifier=Modifier.size(30.dp),
         contentDescription="drawable icons",
         tint=Color.Unspecified
     )
}
```

But in case you want to make a mapping of `image1` and `image2` string values to your corresponding `Drawables` consider this,

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {

    val imageNames = arrayOf("image1", "image2")

    imageNames.forEach { imageString ->
        val imageRes = imageString.mapToMyImageResource()

        Icon(
            painter=painterResource(imageRes),
            modifier=Modifier.size(30.dp),
            contentDescription="drawable icons",
            tint=Color.Unspecified
        )
    }
}

@DrawableRes
fun String.mapToMyImageResource() : Int =
    when (this) {
        "image1" -> {
            R.drawable.ic_1
        }
        "image2" -> {
            R.drawable.ic_2
        }
        else -> {
            R.drawable.ic_default
        }
    }
```

Comment: At first I wanted to use string because there was Text with Icon so I could use the same array for both Icon and Text. I used your first option.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun ImageList() {

//declare your list as resource types
val imagesNames = arrayOf(R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2)

Column {
    imageNames.forEach { image ->
       Icon(
               painter=painterResource(image),
               modifier=Modifier.size(30.dp),
               contentDescription="drawable icons",
               tint=Color.Unspecified
            )
     }
 }
}
```

**Hope you found it helpful!**